# Notation for limit approaching from above/below

Tags: limits, notation

Consider the equation $$f(x)=\frac{4x+8}{x-3}$$
It is known that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 4$$ from above and $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 4$$ from below.
How do you write the "from above/below" formally as part of the equation?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The limit as x approaches $\pm$ infinity is the same numerically. It is 4. However geometrically, it's easy to see the graph is decreasing as x approaches infinity, and the graph is increasing as x approaches negative infinity. How would I write this information down using math notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be like this :
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 4^- \\
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 4^+
$$

Comment: I thought you could only use the superscript +/- on the x is approaching part?

Comment: the function approaches 4 being bigger than 4, we write $4^+$. The same with minus. You can use this notation for the results and the condition.

Answer (score 3):

The typical notations for limits at zero are
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0-} f(x) \\
&\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)
\end{align}
This represents the limits when $x$ is restricted to negative and positive values, respectively.

One-sided limits at infinity make no sense, however. There is no way to approach $\infty$ from above

Answer (score 1):

In general, to express that $f(x)$ is "increasing as $x$ approaches $-\infty$", you would write (assuming the limit exists) that

> $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,a)$

for some appropriate number $a$.  In this case, $a=3$ is the best you can do.  Similarly, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(3,\infty)$, which implies that it is approaching the limit from above.