# Proof $\lim_{n\to\infty} {u_{n+1}\over u_n} = 1_+ \to (u_n)$ has a limit $\ne 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**EDIT : I have doubts about the $1_+$ notation so I'll come back here as soon as I got the answer. In the mean time please consider this question on hold. Feel free to comment if you have any inputs on the $1_+$ notation, thanks.**

First of all I want to let you know that this is an homework assignment I was given.

So here is the question :

> Given $(u_n)_n$ a sequence of strictly positive reals so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {u_{n+1}\over u_n} = 1_+ $
>
> Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n$ exists and is $\ne 0$

Now I tried to use the limit and build from there but to no avail :

$$ \forall \epsilon >0 , \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : n>N \to 1\le{u_{n+1}\over u_n} \le 1+\epsilon $$

Please provide with a few hints to get me started, thanks a lot !

Comment: What does $1_+$ mean?

Comment: That is not true. Take $u_n=n+1$.

Comment: I'm not really sure of the meaning of $1_+$. To be even more confusing I have to agree with the obvious example of Luiz

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: That gives a limit for $u_n$ of something that is $\neq 0$. I don't think $u_n$ could limit to 0 though. At least I can't come up with such an example...

Comment: @SarthakC $\infty$ is not a limit.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: Oh, I think I didn't quite type out what I meant. My bad. I meant that in your example it is not true that the limit of $u_n$ is zero, which is what I think the question means. As in I can't come up with an example where the limit of $u_n$ is zero and it satisfies the given condition.
Given the question as it is, your example works, but I'm not sure that is what the OP intended in the question

Comment: @Furrane: Are you sure $u_n$ is a sequence of positive integers? In that case how could $\lim u_n$ ever be 0?

Comment: Ok guys, I asked about the notation $1_+$ on the class forum. Furthermore Luiz Cordeiro made a great point with his example so I'm quite confuse right now. I will leave this question on stand-by for the time being until I can get a better idea of what's asked.

Comment: @SarthakC $u_n = {1\over n}$ is a strictly positive sequence with a limit of $0$

Comment: @Furrane: But for $u_n=1/n$ it is not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_{n+1}/u_n=1_{+}$, since $u_{n+1}/u_n = n/(n+1)$ which approaches $1$ from below.

Comment: @Furrane: $u_n=1/n$ is a strictly positive sequence, but it is not a sequence of integers. You have $u_n$ as integers in your question

Comment: Oh woops ! Indeed it positive reals, not integers, good catch mate.

Comment: @Furrane: Saying the limit is $1_{+}$ is reasonably common notation for the fact that the limit approaches from above. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/795546 for example

Comment: It seems to be the case SarthakC but then again in that case we have $u_n = n+1$ which fullfil everything yet does not converge. That's why it's wierd.

Comment: I think you aren't supposed to have the part about the existence of the limit in the question. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that $u_n$ are just positive reals. If they are positive integers then I don't think that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ could ever be $0$. I'm also interpreting the question to just mean that it is required to show that the limit of the sequence $u_n$ is not 0, without bothering about whether or not the limit exists.

Just looking at the $1\leq \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ part of what you have gives that $u_{n+1}\geq u_n$ for all $n>N$, which would mean that the sequence is non decreasing beyond some point, and we already know it is positive. This can be used pretty straight-forwardly to show that it cannot limit to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.